# Firebase RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, firebaseui, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I'm developing an app that will display images on RecyclerView by means of Firebase-UI RecyclerView

---

The problem is that when I use StaggeredGridLayoutManager in my RecyclerView there appears very long vertical gaps between horizontal items row.

[Screenshot of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Bks.png)

---

This is my whole Fragment code that I use...

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "Blalba";

private static RecyclerView mGridView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);


    mGridView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mGridView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

    SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
    mGridView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

    setUpFirebaseImagesAdapter();

    return view;


}


public static void setUpFirebaseImagesAdapter() {

    DatabaseReference mImagesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Images");


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebasePostsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageAttribute, FirebaseImagesViewHolder>

            (ImageAttribute.class, R.layout.home_list_item, FirebaseImagesViewHolder.class, mImagesReference) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseImagesViewHolder viewHolder, ImageAttribute model, int position) {

            Log.v("TAGTAG", "Is Scrolling");

            viewHolder.bindPost(model);

        }


    };


    mGridView.setAdapter(mFirebasePostsAdapter);

}

public static class FirebaseImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    Context mContext;

    public FirebaseImagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        mContext = itemView.getContext();

    }

    public void bindPost(final ImageAttribute postAttributes) {

        ImageView PostImageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(postAttributes.getImage_link())
                .into(PostImageView);


    }

}

public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = mSpace;
        outRect.right = mSpace;
        outRect.bottom = mSpace;

        // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
            outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

}

---

My xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
   
    
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:column_count="3"
        app:item_margin="1dp" />

   
</LinearLayout>
```

---

And finally my recyclerView item:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

---

Comment: Check some parts in Recycler View items and make them `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Comment: I added my list RecyclerView item as well, its attributes were--->> android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <<--

Comment: Try using a library of some sort, take a look at Greedolayout for android. This is just a suggestion I haven't taken a closer look on your code yet,